# Pandas groupby and calculate monthly mean but also have month values indicated in a separate column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of time series data and I wish to calculate the monthly mean for values over several years. which can be done with,

```
df_monthly_mean = df_preErup.groupby('month')['values'].mean()
```

This will give a pandas core series of the monthly mean values (12 values corresponding to Jan to Dec). But is there a way to have another column which shows the corresponding months (i.e 1 to 12)?

I have tried to make a list (1 to 12) and convert it into a pandas series and concatenate both series. But the indices get mixed up and each month doesn't align properly resulting in nan values.

```
#list of month values
months_numbered = []
for i in range (1,13):
    months_numbered.append(i) 

#Convert to pandas series
months_no_series = pd.Series(months_numbered)

#Concat
df_preErup_MMean =pd.concat([months_no_series,df_monthly_mean],axis =1)
```

Comment: Read this section on aggregating in pandas- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation

Answer (score 0):

Why not assign the result of your `groupby - mean` directly to the same dataframe?

```
df_preErup['Monthly Mean'] = df_preErup.groupby('month')['values'].mean()
```

Comment: That would be possible. But it wouldn't make much sense to have on the same table. Since I have a large number of data (i.e 01/01/2010 to 31/08/2019) but what I am expecting is only 12 values corresponding to the 12 months,(i.e mean value for Jan for years 2010 to 2019, mean value for Feb 2010 to 2019... and so on for other months as well)
 For example, the dates dataset looks something like this, 01/01/2010, 02/01/2010,03/01/2010................,25/08/2010,............................22/06/2015,.....................31/10/2019.